# SDL2: Texture not rendering to screen

Tags: textures, rendering, sdl, sdl2

I'm trying to render a BMP image, but nothing is showing up other than the draw color. I have most of my code in a header file.

[game.h]

```
#ifndef __Game__
#define __Game__

#include <string>
#include "SDL.h"

using namespace std;

class Game {
public:
    Game();

    bool init(const char*, int, int, int, int, int);
    bool isRunning();
    void update();
    void render();
    void eventHandle();
    void exit();
    SDL_Texture* getTexture();
    SDL_Texture* loadBMPTexture(const char*); 

private:
    SDL_Window* window = NULL;
    SDL_Renderer* renderer = NULL;
    SDL_Texture* texture;

    bool running;
};

Game::Game() {}

bool Game::init(const char* winTitle, int xpos, int ypos, int width, int height, int flags) {
    bool success = true;

    if (SDL_Init(SDL_INIT_EVERYTHING) < 0) {
        SDL_ShowSimpleMessageBox(SDL_MESSAGEBOX_ERROR, "An Error Has Occured", ("SDL_Error:" + ((string)SDL_GetError())).c_str() , NULL);
        bool success = false;
    }
    else {
        window = SDL_CreateWindow(winTitle, xpos, ypos, width, height, flags);
        if (window == NULL) {
            SDL_ShowSimpleMessageBox(SDL_MESSAGEBOX_ERROR, "An Error Has Occured", ("SDL_Error:" + ((string)SDL_GetError())).c_str(), NULL);
            bool success = false;
        }
        else {
            renderer = SDL_CreateRenderer(window, -1, SDL_RENDERER_SOFTWARE);
            if (renderer == NULL) {
                SDL_ShowSimpleMessageBox(SDL_MESSAGEBOX_ERROR, "An Error Has Occured", ("SDL_Error:" + ((string)SDL_GetError())).c_str(), NULL);
                bool success = false;
            }
            else
            {
                SDL_Rect srcRect;
                SDL_Rect destRect;
                SDL_Surface* pTempSurface = SDL_LoadBMP("./resources/img4.bmp");
                if (pTempSurface == NULL) {
                    SDL_ShowSimpleMessageBox(SDL_MESSAGEBOX_ERROR, "An Error Has Occured", ("SDL_Error:" + ((string)SDL_GetError())).c_str(), NULL);
                }
                SDL_FillRect(pTempSurface,NULL,0xFFFFFFFF);
                SDL_Texture* texture = SDL_CreateTextureFromSurface(renderer, pTempSurface);
                SDL_FreeSurface(pTempSurface);

                destRect.x = srcRect.x = 0;
                destRect.y = srcRect.y = 0;

                SDL_QueryTexture(texture,NULL,NULL,&srcRect.w, &srcRect.h);
                cout << srcRect.w << endl;
                int w, h;
                SDL_GetRendererOutputSize(renderer,&w,&h);
                destRect.w = w;
                destRect.h = h;
                cout << w;
                SDL_SetRenderDrawColor(renderer, 255, 255, 0, 0);

                SDL_RenderCopy(renderer, texture, &destRect, &srcRect);

                SDL_RenderPresent(renderer);
                running = true;
            }
        }
    }
    return success;
}

void Game::render() {
    //SDL_SetRenderDrawColor(renderer, 0, 0, 0, 255);

    SDL_RenderClear(renderer);

    SDL_RenderPresent(renderer);
}
void Game::eventHandle() {
    SDL_Event e;

    if (SDL_PollEvent(&e)) {
        switch (e.type) {
        case SDL_QUIT:
            running = false;
            break;
        }
    }
}
void Game::exit() {
    SDL_DestroyWindow(window);
    window = NULL;
    SDL_DestroyRenderer(renderer);
    renderer = NULL;
    SDL_Quit();
}

bool Game::isRunning() {
    return running;
}
SDL_Texture* Game::loadBMPTexture(const char* path) {
    SDL_Surface* tempSurface = SDL_LoadBMP(path);
    SDL_Texture* returnTexture = SDL_CreateTextureFromSurface(renderer, tempSurface);
    SDL_FreeSurface(tempSurface);
    return returnTexture;
}
void Game::update() {

}
SDL_Texture* Game::getTexture() {
    return texture;
}

#endif
```

[main.cpp]

```
#include "SDL.h"
#include <string>
#include <iostream>
#include "Game.h"
using namespace std;

int SCREEN_WIDTH = 1280;
int SCREEN_HEIGHT = 720;

const Uint8* keystate;
//keystate = SDL_GetKeyboardState(NULL);

Game* game = NULL;

int main(int argc, char* argv[]) {
    game = new Game();

    game->init("Game Title [Confused]",SDL_WINDOWPOS_UNDEFINED, SDL_WINDOWPOS_UNDEFINED, SCREEN_WIDTH, SCREEN_HEIGHT, SDL_WINDOW_SHOWN);

    while (game->isRunning()) {
        game->eventHandle();
        game->render();
    }

    game->exit();
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For no apparent reason, you are filling your loaded image with a solid white color using `SDL_FillRect`. Also, you seem to clear the renderer without rerendering the texture. You need to `SDL_RenderCopy` the texture again after clearing the renderer.